# Airflow Kubernetes DAG creates pod but stop running on queued

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, airflow

I have an Airflow 1.10.15 (a.k.a. Bridge Release) in my AWS Kubernetes cluster. It uses KubernetesExecutor.

I have a Hello World KubernetesExecutor DAG which should print Hello World. When triggering the DAG, it creates a pod but it never prints the Hello World.

Here are all the logs after the pod has been completed running:
[image]

Describing the pod will give me logs which has no errors or failures:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check Task logs, not Kubernetes logs. Kubernetes logs keep information about "atempting to run" the task (and looks that it's all ok here).

Now, when you log anything in the running tasks, it does not go to the k8S logs - it goes to task logs. By default, when you configure Airflow, the logs for tasks are stored separately - basically every task has its own log. This is in order so that you can pull the logs and see them in Airflow UI when you click on "logs" for this particular task execution.

Just check it in the UI or in the "${AIRFLOW_HOME}/logs" folder.

Comment: I'm seeing similar output as above for my project but I'm seeing the pod logs in Airflow UI, no task logs. And right after that line I see "Stream closed EOF for <namespace>/<pod> (base)". The pod goes into Completed state but the DAG retries the task. I'm also trying to figure out where the "Running <TaskInstance: ..." line is coming from since the other lines seem to be coming from Airflow code. I also have a volume mount with mountPath: "${AIRFLOW_HOME}/logs" & name: "airflow-logs"

Comment: Figured it out. Came across this article: https://szeevs.medium.com/handling-airflow-logs-with-kubernetes-executor-25c11ea831e4. You need to add a custom logging handler for the task itself